# How to change the GUI of MAS in JADE?

Tags: java, user-interface, agents-jade

[This is the GUI that i'm using right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqnzB.gif)

[And this is the GUI that i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjQjB.jpg)

How do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I You have to start JADE sniffer agent.

As provided in JADE [documentation](http://jade.tilab.com/documentation/tutorials-guides/sniffer/introduction/), in a direct citation, the Sniffer can be started in three different ways:

- First you can click on the Start Sniffer icon  on the rma toolbar. By doing so a sniffer agent is created and is assigned the name snifferX, where X is a progressive number starting from 0.
- Second you can click on the Start Sniffer item in the rma Tools menu. This performs the same task as previously described.
- You can manually create a new instance of the Sniffer: this is useful if you want the Sniffer to have a name different from the standard one. To do so you have to click on the Start New Agent icon on the rma toolbar: this brings up a dialog box in which you have to provide some informations where in the Agent Name field you have to provide the Sniffer name. In the Class Name field you have to write jade.tools.sniffer.Sniffer because the Sniffer class is contained in the package jade.tools.sniffer.